# Best practice when converting DataColumn values to an array of strings?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, datatable

Best practice when converting DataColumn values to an array of strings?

**[Edit]**
All values for certain DataColumn for all DataTable rows to be converted to an array of string?

Comment: Can you specify? Any Datarow has the ItemArray property which gives you back an object array in the same sequence as the columns defined for it. Converting the objects to strings would then be as easy as calling ToString() on each value, but maybe it is somethign else you want...

Comment: Values of DataColumn to be converted to an array of strings, but I'm looking for best method for implementing this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If I understood your goal you want to specify a particular column and return all its values as a string array.

Try these approaches out:

```
int columnIndex = 2; // desired column index

// for loop approach        
string[] results = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
for (int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; index++)
{
    results[index] = dt.Rows[index][columnIndex].ToString();
}

// LINQ
var result = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                    .Select(row => row[columnIndex].ToString())
                    .ToArray();
```

You could replace `columnIndex` with `columnName` instead, for example:

```
string columnName = "OrderId";"
```

**EDIT:** you've asked for a string array specifically but in case you're flexible about the requirements I would prefer a `List<string>` to avoid the need to determine the array length prior to the for loop in the first example and simply add items to it. It's also a good opportunity to use a foreach loop instead.

I would then rewrite the code as follows:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    list.Add(row[columnIndex].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DataRow.ItemArray Property -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx

Also, which version are you using?  You should check out the DataTableExtensions class -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.aspx

And the DataRowExtensions class -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx

Comment: `DataRow.ItemArray` returns all the values in a row as an array.  I think the OP wants all the values in a column as an array.  Perhaps you can expand your answer to help explain how `DataRow.ItemArray` and the `DataTableExtensions` class can help?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I found it in my Google search trying to do something similar. I wanted to create a list from all the values contained in a specific row of my datatable. In my code example below, I added a SQL datasource to my project in Visual Studio using the GUI wizards and I dropped the needed table adapter into the designer.

```vb
'Create a private DataTable
Private authTable As New qmgmtDataSet.AuthoritiesDataTable

'Fill the private table using the table adapter 
Me.AuthoritiesTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.authTable)

'Make the list of values
Dim authNames As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(From value As qmgmtDataSet.AuthoritiesRow In Me.authTable.Rows Select names.authName)
```