# How to populate a List of strings from a DataTable?

Tags: vb.net, list, datatable

I'm trying to populate a `List` with a column of a `DataTable` in order to later convert it to a `AutoCompleteStringCollection` later. Is there a neater way to do it than the "good old" `For Each`?

Is there a way to use `myDataTable.Rows.CopyTo` for this task?

Cheers! = )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this :- [Best practice when converting DataColumn values to an array of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077592/best-practice-when-converting-datacolumn-values-to-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this, but didn't find this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so.  You can do some fancy LINQ expressions, but they all get boiled down to looping through the rows...