# How to fill ImageList from a particular column of a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, windows, timagelist

I have a DataTable which is having a hundred of rows, and many columns.
One of the column is - "ImageThumbnail"
I want to display the thumbnail in one control on form. This control expects an "ImageList" as its image source.
So I like my ImageList control to get populated from "ImageThumbnail" column of the dataset. I could do it using looping through all rows in DataTable, but I believe there must be some efficient method.

Comment: Do you want to display images from all rows in one control at the same time? What have you tried? Show your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quickly trying this for myself, it appears to me that this boils down to trying to get the values from a single `DataColumn` in an efficient way.  After I realised this I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2077822/340045) which suggested 2 solutions.  I applied these to my test for `ImageLists` and I have included my code below:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(Image));

dt.Rows.Add("Img1", Properties.Resources.Img_1);
dt.Rows.Add("Img2", Properties.Resources.Img_2);
dt.Rows.Add("Img3", Properties.Resources.Img_3);
dt.Rows.Add("Img4", Properties.Resources.Img_4);

ImageList imgList = new ImageList();

//// Loop Approach:
//for (int idx = 0; idx < dt.Rows.Count; idx++)
//{
//    imgList.Images.Add(dt.Rows[idx]["Image"] as Image);
//}

// LINQ Approach:
imgList.Images.AddRange(dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["Image"] as Image).ToArray());
```

In my opinion the LINQ Approach is more succinct, but the Loop Approach is perhaps quicker to understand and so is more readable.  I am not sure which of these is going to be more efficient, or if they both end up with similar IL code.  However, the LINQ Approach uses the `AddRange` and `ToArray` built-in methods which could include efficiency improvements (or may do in the future).